# what is the order of function overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, object-composition

I have a doubt on the result of the question below. When calling function `f` from main, the call goes to `f(B &)` although I have int operator overloaded and `f(int)` is defined first.

If I comment out the `f(B &)` function, then the call goes to `f(int)` and prints 5.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    int y;
    public:
    A(int y=2):y(y){}
    int getValue(){
        cout<<y<<endl;
    }
};
class B{
    int x;
    public:
    A a;
    B(int x=5):x(x){}
    operator int(){
        return x;
    }
};
void f(int x){
    cout<<x<<endl;
}
void f(B &b){
    b.a.getValue();
}
int main() {
    B b;
    f(b);
}
```

I was expecting it to go to `f(int)` function and `print 5` but it instead `prints 2`. Why it does not go to `f(int)` instead of `f(B &)`. Why is this behavior happening, can anyone please explain?

Comment: Simply because f(B) is an exact match. An exact match will always beat a match that requires a conversion.

Comment: `catch` clauses are searched in their order of declaration. Overloaded functions are not.

Answer (score 4):

Function overload resolution is based on which function is a better match, not which function is "defined first".

You're passing a `B`, so `f(B&)` is an *exact* match.

`f(int)` is not as it requires a conversion.

There's nothing in your program to trigger said conversion, though it would be attempted if `f(B&)` did not exist.

---

By the way, your `getValue` is actually more like `printValue`. It currently has an `int` return type, but does not actually return anything, so your program has undefined behaviour. You can fix this by making it return `void`, but you'd probably be better off making it `return y` instead.

Comment: Try commenting out the f(B &) function, then it triggers the only function it has which is f(int).

Comment: @MFCDev Of course. It makes sense that, if `f(B&)` does not exist, it will not be called.

Comment: if you comment ```f(B&)``` it will try to implict converse it to f(int).
You might want to read about implicit and explicit conversions because it is whats happening here

Comment: @MaxLanghof Mm was debating doing that. Fine, will add ;)